# Seeminly identical CSS and markup rendering differently

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have purchased the [Ambrosia](http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB06SM719) bootstrap theme but am having problems implementing the login page. My login page can be found [here](https://nzdogshows.azurewebsites.net/Account/SignupLogin).

The issues I'm having are the little Twitter, Facebook, and Info icons to the left of a bit of text within the page. For some odd reason mine is missing the bit of space to the right, between the icon and the words that follow. I can't for the life of me spot the differences. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is throw a space between the icon and the text of the button:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-twitter"><i class="icon icon-twitter"></i>Twitter</a>
```

To:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-twitter"><i class="icon icon-twitter"></i> Twitter</a>
```

Comment: Not so much a space but, &nbsp;

Comment: Twitter Bootstrap themselves don't use non breaking spaces - http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#icons

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the point. There are other ways I could achieve it too. The sample login page did not have an extra space, neither does mine, both reference the same CSS, yet render differently. I implemented it as identically as I could, so I may well be missing something obvious.

Comment: The demo site DOES use a space in their buttons, I suggest you look at the code on the demo site properly!

Comment: You're right. The button uses a space. But the "Info" icon does not.

Comment: Yes, the info button also uses a space: <i class="icon-exclamation-sign"></i> <a href="#">Recover password or username »</a>

Comment: Somehow I completely missed that. I went with a CSS solution instead of a space.

Answer (score 0):

A sitewide fix would be the following:
change:

```
[class^="icon-"]:before, [class*=" icon-"]:before {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: inherit;
}
```

to

```
[class^="icon-"]:before, [class*=" icon-"]:before {
        display: inline-block;
        text-decoration: inherit;
        margin-right: 5px;
    }
```

in font-awesome.css. Although if it's just these you will need to put a space in front of the word Facebook and Twitter like Dontfeedthecode says :)

Answer (score 0):

Just tab the spacebar before the word spacebar and there you go, whitespace.

Instead of

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-facebook"><i class="icon icon-facebook"></i>Facebook</a>
```

Use

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-facebook"><i class="icon icon-facebook"></i> Facebook</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add padding right to the following section in your css file font-awesome.css ln160 :

```
/* Bootstrap 2.0 sprites.less reset */
[class^="icon-"],
[class*=" icon-"] {
 display: inline;
width: auto;
height: auto;
line-height: normal;
vertical-align: baseline;
background-image: none;
background-position: 0% 0%;
background-repeat: repeat;
padding-right: 5px; <!-- This is the important line --!>
}
```

Comment: You should not modify bootstrap classes. Instead you should add your own classes to the elements(in addition to bootstrap)!